# Convert Salesforce IDs from 15 digit to 18 digit using sql code/function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, salesforce

We are currently pulling in data from SalesForce to SQL Database tables.  There are 2 custom fields on different objects that were created for the Lead ID and a look up for which event/task is linked (this can be an account id, contact id, or lead id).  Both of these are pulling over the 15 digit ID.

I am trying to find out if there is any SQL code or a SQL function that will allow me to convert that 15 digit to an 18 digit ID.

I need to have that 18 digit ID to join back to the other objects.

We have already tried using the `CASESAFEID(Id)` function in SalesForce, but with the API that was already set up and the visibility levels our particular ETL is not showing that field.  Also, we would need to get a consultant to mess with the look up column.

I would like to take the 15 digit ID and convert it to the 18 digit code. If the SalesforceID is `0035000002tAzbu`, how do I get the converted 18 digit value to be `0035000002tAzbuACC`.  I need to get that last 3 digits using SQL query or SQL function.

Comment: Can you show some examples of how the 15 digit value should be converted to an 18 digit value - we don't know what conversion works with your system.

Comment: This Id would show as 0035000002tAzbu in the cell, but should be 0035000002tAzbuAAC.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but edit it into your question rather than adding it as a comment. So what is the rule begin used to convert? How does one know to add 'AAC' at the end?

Comment: On a sidenote you will get better responses if you use the salesforce.stackexchange.com site

Comment: Even though I am looking for SQL code to get the 18 digit it would be better to go onto the salesforce.stackexchange.com site?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your question, but it seemed like you were asking for the algorithm to produce the final 3 characters. if that is the case then that would be a better suited area to ask the question. It can be confusing

Comment: No, I was looking for any SQL code that would add the 3 digits in a table.  We are using SSIS to pull the data from Salesforce into our Data Warehouse, but there are 2 columns inside Salesforce that only have the 15 digit when it comes into the table.  I wanted to know if there was any possible SQL code that would pull those into the table vs doing changes within Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a custom function in your sql database.

e.g. in snowflake, you can make a function like this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dw.my_schema.f_sfdc_ch15_to_ch18("txt" string)
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS '
    if ( txt == undefined || txt == "" || typeof txt == "undefined" || txt == null) {
        return ;
    } else {
        var id15, id18;
        
        if (txt.length == 18) {
            return txt;
        } else if (txt.length == 15) {
            id15 = [txt.trim()];
        } else {
            return "";
        }
        for ( var x=0; x < id15.length; x++ ) {
            var s = "";
            for ( var i=0; i<3; i++) {
                var f = 0;
                for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
                    var c = id15[x].charAt(i*5+j);
                    if (c>="A" && c<="Z") {
                        f+=1<<j;
                    }
                }
                s += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345".charAt(f);
            }
            id18 = id15[x]+s;
        }
    }
    return id18.toString();
    ';
```

and use it like this

```
select dw.my_schema.f_sfdc_ch15_to_ch18(id15) from mytable;
```

Answer (score -1):

This value can be computed. Check out this flowchart.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29299786/3135974

[image]