# Converting Salesforce IDs from 15 character to 18 character in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-functions, salesforce, azure-data-explorer

I'm new to Azure Data Explorer and working with Salesforce data. A very common data cleansing is to check the Salesforce Account Id is 18 character long. I know how to transform the id in MSSQL but not sure how to build the same function or script in Azure Data Explorer. I need a similar solution to this [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910479/convert-salesforce-ids-from-15-digit-to-18-digit-using-sql-code-function) in Azure Data Explorer.

Has anyone tried standardizing Salesforce Id that are 15 character in Azure Data Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function for this in KQL. You'll need to write your own.